# Is there an IntelliJ IDEA action that select a word if there is no selection but stay unchanged if there is?

Tags: intellij-idea, macros

I want to write a macro that if there is no selection it automatically operates on the current word, otherwise it operates on the selection. However I cannot find a suitable action, EditorSelectWord keeps on expanding the selection forever.

p.s. The macro is meant to change "xyz" to "{@code xyz}", but it also needs to change "x/y/z" to "{@code x/y/z}".

Comment: It looks like macros only support a fixed list of steps that are always executed, without if statements: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/using-macros-in-the-editor.html.

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ IDEA does not appear to be the best tool for this specific job. It looks like macros only support a fixed list of steps that will always be executed, without the possibility for if statements: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/using-macros-in-the-editor.html.

You could use Ctrl-W manually when there is no selection, but it would of course be much nicer if the macro could handle it. Another possibility is to use a tool like the stream editor [sed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed). The substitution command of sed might be usable in your case, unless the text occurs in places where you do not want to substitute it:

```
sed 's/xyz/{@code xyz}/g' inputFileName > outputFileName
```

It might also be a great reason to write a small program of your own that for example modifies only specific strings in Javadocs in your source files.

Comment: Thanks. However, I still want to do this with a single keystroke inside IDEA, and quite often I need to @code-fy multiple words and that's why selection should be supported.

Comment: Finally I create 2 macros. Now I have to remember 2 keystokes but that's OK.

Comment: Nice work around! If you really want to use a single keystroke, you can always consider creating a small plugin, but that's a lot more work than two macros. (See http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/getting_started.html for more information on writing a plugin.)